# How to livereload nginx to serve Angular ssr on Docker

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, google-cloud-run, angular-universal

How to add liveReload on angular13 and serve on nginx
my default.conf and docker as below it work but miss the livereload, I used angular universal, on Angular 13 , the SSR somehow not work.

in Angular 8 server folder
app.moudle.ts we can set liveReload:true, but in Angular 13 server folder it only generated main.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AngularUniversalModule.forRoot({
      viewsPath: join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser'),

      bundle: require('../server/main'),
      liveReload: true
    })
  ]
})
```

nginx
default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  domainname.com www.domainname.com;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        gzip on;
        gzip_types application/javascript image/* text/css;
        gunzip on;
    }
   
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
# STEP 1 build static website
FROM node:alpine as builder
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache make git
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app
# Create app/nginx directory and copy default.conf to it
WORKDIR /app/nginx
COPY nginx/conf.d/default.conf /app/nginx/
# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/
RUN cd /app && npm set progress=false && npm install -f
# Copy project files into the docker image
COPY .  /app
RUN cd /app && npm run build:ssr

# STEP 2 build a small nginx image with static website
FROM nginx:alpine
# Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
# From 'builder' copy website to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ctd-13scss/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
# From 'builder' copy default nginx configuration to the configuration conf.d folder of nginx
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
#expose
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My question is how to add the SSR to DOCKER ?

Comment: Can you check this [page](https://tiangolo.medium.com/angular-in-docker-with-nginx-supporting-environments-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-bb9f1724e984) once? Which might be helpful to you.

Comment: Can you please add the COPY SSR to docker, Please.